# JavaScript merge multiple Boolean arrays and the OR || operator

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to merge this array using or || operator

```
[[true,false,false],[false,false,false],[false,false,true]]
```

so that the output is

```
[true,false,true]
```

is this possible with map or reduce or similar?

Edit: Sorry for the unclear question - yes it was to vertically merge all sub arrays together. So the following input:

```
[[true,false,false],[false,false,false],[false,false,true],[false,false,true]]
```

would produce the same output:

```
[true,false,true]
```

Comment: What is the logical condition for merging?

Comment: 1. Do you want that first `true` to be `a[0][0] || a[0][1] || a[0][2]` or `a[0][0] || a[1][0] || a[2][0]`? 2. What have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: Well, thanks to the unclear question, you now have answers both ways. :-) [marvel308's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46132127/157247) if you want the first one, [Nina's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46132147/157247) if you want the second.

Comment: To put TJ's observation in another way, are you merging vertically or horizontally?  Are you merging each array or are you merging value at an index across all arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reduce the arrays with mapping the same index values.

```js
var array = [[true, false, false], [false, false, false], [false, false, true]],
    result = array.reduce((a, b) => a.map((c, i) => b[i] || c));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't really need the `||` when you use `some`:

```js
var array = [[true, false, false], [false, false, false], [false, false, true]];

var result = array[0].map( (_, i) => array.some(a => a[i]));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: you could use `Boolean` as cb.

Comment: What a neat horizontal merge solution - Thanks. But I meant to do a vertical merge.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in the following way

```js
let arr = [[true,false,false],[false,false,false],[false,false,true]];

arr = arr.map(function(element){
    return element.reduce(function(a, b){
        return (a|b);
    })
})

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Depends on which way they want to do it. There are two that fit the question's input and output.

Comment: what I inferred was that he wants to OR all subarrays and make a new one

Comment: @marvel308 just be clear.. you're not logical-OR-ing this, you are bitwise-OR-ing