# How to turn multiple arrays of booleans to single array of booleans

Tags: javascript

I am finding it hard to work out the best way to take multiple arrays of the same length and merge them into a single array of true values. So if `true` is in the index position, the new array should have `true`, else just leave `false`.

```
const array1 = [true, true, false, false, true]
const array = [true, false, false, true, false]
```

Output is:

```
[true, true, false, true, true]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript merge multiple Boolean arrays and the OR || operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46132107/javascript-merge-multiple-boolean-arrays-and-the-or-operator)

Comment: That is for an array of arrays. There was no answer for simple seperate arrays. Also, that changes everything to the main arrays length of the arrays inside lengths, so in their example 3 booleans, where as, i needed the original length of the array to be the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with `map`. It will generate new array for you. Inside `map` there are certain arguments you can pass `current value` and `iteration` using which you will get the data from second array and then put an `OR` || condition to get the expected output.

```js
const array1 = [true, true, false, false, true];
const array = [true, false, false, true, false];

const output = array1.map((val,i)=>val || array[i]);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank you, can you explain what each part does, so i can research how to do it?

Comment: Ok thank you i will check it out. Super helpful, i was trying to use reduce.

Comment: well explained :)

Comment: The value of true is returned always in this example due to 'Operator precedence' right? Because if true exists it takes precedence over false and is put into the new array returned by map. Think that's important to note for beginners to understand why this returns true.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and check any of `e` **OR** `array[i]` is **true**, here `e` belong to each element of `array1` and `array[i]` means each element of `array` respectively.Finally, it will make a `newArray` after conditional checking inside the map function.

```js
const array1 = [true, true, false, false, true];
const array = [true, false, false, true, false];
var newArray = array1.map((e, i) => Boolean(e | array[i]));
console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, it's very helpful.

Comment: @learncodes123 glad it helps you somehow, best of luck :)